# Core Data Guidance

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am using Core Data considerably in my app. There is a lot of population and fetching. However, my app is becoming very slow. Please if you could suggest some optimisations.

I'm using the following code to fetch from Core Data:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:[(RICAELLEAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError* error;

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[(RICAELLEAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

In the view this will appear each time. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, not sure if there's enough code to figure out what's going on.  Have you measured and profiled?

Answer (score 0):

`fetchRequest` is never released.

Comment: @ Nico thanks make sense and is it good to call again and again when need to show data???

Comment: Maybe he's using ARC - if so, no need to release anything. Can't be sure though.